# Is it a good idea to initialize Crashlytics, on android's onCreate method?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics for android and it really helped me to fix many of my crashes. But today I had a little problem with it.

When I tried to test crashlytics on 2.3.3 Galaxy S device, which is connected to internet by wi-fi(with proxy), I saw black screen on device for about 2:30 minutes. While debugging; I see that `Crashlytics.start(this)` code is not async. It waits to establish a connection and thus onCreate method can not be finished by UI thread.(This explains black screen).

I know this a proxy issue(proxy setting is a bit buggy on 2.3.x devices) but waiting for about 2:30 minutes made my app black screen. This worried me that this may happen on any other real life conditions such as poor internet connection.

I will try to put `Crashlytics.start(this)` function into an asynctask and will try this on every activities onCreate method. (AFAIK there is no method to check isCrashlyticsInitialized)

Does anyone have better idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

**LOGCAT:**

```
 10-02 16:01:38.410: D/Crashlytics(1561): Initializing Crashlytics 0.9.11.11 
 10-02 16:04:19.664: E/Crashlytics(1561): Network error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until the network is available.
[URL=https://settings.crashlytics.com/api/v2/keys/KEY/platforms/android/apps/com.myapp/settings.json?libVersion=0.9.11.11&bundleVersion=441210&shortBundleVersion=2.1];[class java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Marc from Crashlytics here. Crashlytics.start() does all the heavy lifting in a background thread in newer versions of the SDK. Your logs indicate you're using v0.9.11. Once you update to the latest version (v1.0.4), you'll be fine keeping Crashlytics.start in the Application subclass. Please contact us at support at crashlytics dot com if you need any help updating!

Comment: Thanks @Marc but crashlytics library is automaticaly copied to libs dir of my project by crashlytics plugin. I've tried to update your plugin but there are no updates as far as I see. From eclipse plugin update site your http://download.crashlytics.com/android/eclipse link retrieves version 0.9.4 which is currently I'am using. I removed and reinstalled crashlytics plugin(still v0.9.4) and I tried to add crashlytics support to a new sample project. Copied crashlitics jar's information is; Specification-Title: Crashlytics Android SDK
Implementation-Version: 11
Specification-Version: 0.9.11

Comment: Should I manually find and copy crashlytics.jar? If so where can I find it?

Comment: I have this as my software site in Eclipse for Crashlytics: https://crashlytics.com/download/eclipse. If you try this one you still only get the old version? I just checked and my version says it's on 1.1.0

Comment: Thanks @jmrmb80 I'll try your link when I get home(it causes some errors right now, I guess that is because of our proxy here).

Comment: @jmrmb80, that is the correct location! You should be all set after downloading from there. Also, you can always check here for instructions for downloading the latest updates: https://crashlytics.com/downloads

Comment: Hey @marcr I also got the black screen in v 1.1.5.4. It was when I was testing crashlytics by throwing an exception. It went black on 3rd launch, when it actually sent the crash reports. I know this because that's when I got the reports in my dashboard. I was crashing immediately after calling crashlytics.start(), maybe that's why it couldn't send the reports in the first 2 tries. However, when I removed the exception, it sent the reports and the screen was black for about 2 seconds on my Nexus 4 running Android 4.4.

Comment: @droidster Shoot us an email (support at crashlytics dot com) and we'll help you out!

Comment: Profiling the version 1.1.13.29 of the sdk I noticed that "Crashlytics.start" method takes up to 3 seconds to execute if the manifest has multiple processes.

Comment: @marcr, can we have the guarantee that right after "Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());" is called, Crashlytics.getInstance() will work? It seems to me that as the initialisation is asynchronous,  Crashlytics.getInstance() cannot be use right after initialising it