# It takes a lot of time Loading the Layout of an activity due to AsyncTask

Tags: android, layout, android-asynctask

I am willing to do a Launching Activity in which I charge the content of all the Database. What is happening to me is that it takes like two seconds to the activity to load the Layout, which is really ugly (it shows a white layout).

Here is the code:

```
    public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Crashlytics.start(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
    Void params = null;

    Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-44871768-1");

    tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Home Screen");

    // Send a screen view for "Home Screen"
    tracker.send(MapBuilder
        .createAppView()
        .build()
    );



    // Clear the screen name field when we're done.
    tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, null);


    new LoadDBAsyncTask().execute(params);

}


  private class LoadDBAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
      @Override 
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Set screen name on the tracker to be sent with all hits.

            Constants.createDB(getApplicationContext());
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(result){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, QuickGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } 
         }
     }
```

And this is the layout I inflate

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuickGameActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/launcher_activity"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashlytics may be your problem here. I asked a question an got an answer for it. You should check your crashlytics api version.

[Is it a good idea to initialize Crashlytics, on android's onCreate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140066/is-it-a-good-idea-to-initialize-crashlytics-on-androids-oncreate-method)

Comment: Perfect! I have introduced it in the AsyncTask and it works properly

Comment: Great;) But you don't need to use an extra asynctask for crashlytics, just be sure you are using the latest version of crashlytics jar.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Constants.createDB(getApplicationContext())` twice. Once in the AsyncTask and once in `onCreate()`.

The call happening in onCreate() is on the UI thread.

Comment: It was commented but after posting it took the // out. So it shouldn't be the mistake. Could you please look through the code again?

Comment: Is `activity_launcher` an empty layout?

Comment: No, I have updated the layout. But I just see a white screen with the action bar.

Comment: What does `createDB()` do anyway? Could you post that?